# Resubmission to journal of same publisher after paper was not reviewed by another journal

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted an article to one of the JAMA network specialty journals. I asked for my article to be referred to a second specialty journal if not deemed acceptable for publication by the first. However, the editor of the first journal did not send it out for peer review and thus it was not referred to the second specialty journal at all.

I still think my manuscript could be a good fit for that second journal. Does anyone know the policy for re-submitting since it was technically not reviewed by that second journal?

Comment: How much time has elapsed since your submission?

Comment: And, have you gotten a letter of rejection?

Comment: Have you heard back at all? If not, then you need to withdraw your paper before resubmitting it elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a clear statement from the editor/publisher that the paper has been rejected, then you can submit it anywhere you choose. Different journals, even with the same publisher, have different policies about what they will publish.

If you have formally withdrawn the paper with a written statement to the editor/publisher, then you can also submit it anywhere you choose. An email is all it takes.

But the rule is "one journal at a time". Editors frown (pretty deeply) if they learn you have multiple concurrent submissions. Don't go there.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful insight.

Answer (score 4):

Broadly speaking journals aren't aware what other journals are doing, even if they're operated by the same publisher. In fact unless you are in the (very rare especially for large journals) case where the same employee is assigned to both journals, the second journal is not likely to even notice.

You can just submit your manuscript to the second journal.

Comment: Not until you withdraw from the first journal or it is rejected.

Comment: @Buffy it's already been rejected (desk rejected, in the case of the OP's paper).

Comment: How do you conclude that? I don't find any such statement in the question.

Comment: @Buffy I'd interpret "didn't send out for peer review" to mean a desk reject. It's probably good to verify here since some of our visitors are confused about the process, but I don't think that applies here.

Comment: @BryanKrause, both you and the OP may be making assumptions here. "Didn't", "Won't", etc mean different things and a rejection needs to be explicit, not assumed.

Comment: My apologies - yes it's been desk rejected from the first journal.

Comment: "the second journal is not likely to even notice" Probably not. Sometimes there is a question during the submission process like "Has the manuscript been submitted to any other journal of [publisher] before?". Then of course you should answer the truth. Personally I usually would disclose the info of previous submissions with the same publisher in the cover letter, including some short remarks about improvements made to the manuscript in the meantime thanks to the previous constructive feedback, if appropriate.